# Removing a value from a map

Tags: java

I have a `Map<Something, List<String>> map`.
I want to remove a `String` from the `List<String>`.

Is that possible ? How do I do that ?

I don't want to remove the mapping, just alter the 'value' of an entry.

I have tried `map.values().remove("someString")`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `map.get(somethingKey).remove("someString")`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove a String from a particular map item, you should use something like this:

```
if (map.containsKey(somethingParticular) && map.get(somethingParticular)!=null)
    map.get(somethingParticular).remove("someString")
```

if you want to remove "someString" from all map items, its better to do thw following:

```
for(List<String> list : map.values()) {
    if (list!=null)
        list.remove("someString");
}
```

Comment: Good idea for the `containsKey()` and null checks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually have a value to index into the map also.

Then you can do something like this:

`map.get(mapValue).remove("someString")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: map.get(key).remove("someString")

Answer (score 1):

`map.values()` returns a Collection of `List<String>`. You have to iterate over the values and search for your key in every list.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    Collection<List<String>> values = map.values();
    for( List<String> list : values ) {
        list.remove( "someString" );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove the string from all the string lists, or a specific one?

If you want a specific one, then you need to get the `List<String>` by key:

```
map.get(thekey).remove("someString")
```

If you want to remove them all, then you need to *loop over* the values, as they're a collection of `List<String>`'s.

```
for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
    list.remove("someString");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Something, List<String>> myMap = ....;
myMap.get(somethingInstance).remove("someString");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible :

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
intList.add(3);
intList.add(4);
map.put("intlist",intList);
System.out.println(map.get("intlist"));
intList = map.get("intlist");
intList.remove(1);
intList.add(4);     
//they will be the same (same ref)
System.out.println(intList);
System.out.println(map.get("intlist"));
```